# How to get data from cookies that were sent with "httpOnly: true"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In backend, the cookies are sent as below:

```
    jwt.sign(
      payload,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: 31556926 },
      (err, token) =>
        res
          .cookie("token", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 31556926,
          })
          .json({ success: true, newUser })
    );
```

But in frontend, I cannot get the "token" from cookies.

It is not shown in Chrome, and it is said that it is because Chrome doesn't set cookies in localhost.

I tried to use `console.log(document.cookie);` to print it, but nothing showed up in console, and I think it is because the `httpOnly` is set to be ture so the cookies are invisible from `document.cookie`?

Then how can I get this "token" from cookies? I need to send it back **(through socket.io)** to backend for authentication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) set with the `HttpOnly` flag are not accessible from JavaScript.

But cookies in general are sent to the setting server with every request. Once the server instructs your browser to store the cookie, the browser will send back the contents in the `Cookie` header of the request.

Based on your code snippet above, it looks like you're using Express. To access the token from the server

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); // Don't forget to npm install
app.use(cookieParser()); // Before any routes that use the cookie

/* from inside your route handler */
    req.cookies.token
```

Comment: I am using `Socket.io` to send the token back to backend for authentication, so there will be no `req`, is that correct? if so, what should I do? How to, in FE, get the token, send through `socket.io` to BE?

Comment: The cookie will get sent back with the HTTP request that establishes the socket.io connection. Search for "socket.io middleware" or the socketio-auth npm package.